# Mysql query to see if a member has done a lesson

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables: "members_info" and "members_lesson".

Let's say in members_info I have the fields member_id, first_name, last_name
In members_lesson I have members_lesson_id, lesson_id, member_id

I want to create a query where I can see the members that have done one lesson but havent done another one. I tried this query:

```
SELECT members_info.member_id
   FROM members_info
   JOIN member_lessons ON members_info.member_id = member_lessons.member_id
   WHERE member_lessons.lesson_id =6 AND  member_lessons.lesson_id !=7
```

But that query is not working. It works when I only check if the member has done a lesson, but if I want to see if the member has not done another one it doesnt work. Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT --**

I tried this:

```
SELECT members_info
FROM members_info
WHERE member_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM member_lessons WHERE lesson_id = 6)
AND member_id NOT IN (SELECT member_id FROM member_lessons WHERE lesson_id = 7)
```

It does work, but im not sure about performance. Is that way ok? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT members_info
FROM members_info
WHERE member_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM member_lessons WHERE lesson_id = 6)
AND member_id NOT IN (SELECT member_id FROM member_lessons WHERE lesson_id = 7)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT member_id, max(lesson_id)   
FROM member_lessons ml 
group by member_id 
WHERE lesson_id in (6, 7)
having count(distinct lesson_id) = 1
    and max(lesson_id) = 6
```

Comment: since 6 < 7 it'll work, but in it will be more general to use "not exist"